# drush in ddev says [preflight] Package "drupal/core" is not installed

Tags: drush

Whatever command I run using *ddev drush* , I am always getting the response *" [preflight] Package "drupal/core"* is not installed". But drupal is already installed and website is working fine.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Try running `ddev composer install`

Comment: Is the whole site working fine? I have the same problem and when I try to enable a module it fails with this same error

Comment: Is drush/drush installed in the Drupal codebase?

Comment: drush/drush is already installed in the codebase. If we run `ddev ssh` and then run `vendor/bin/drush` everything works well.